# Jupyter notebook autocomplete shows too much

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to autocomplete the path in jupyter notebook. After I press 'tab', it shows much more than folder or file. I think those are build-in function of python. Is there any way to show only path and files while autocomplete the path?
Thanks!

[image: jupyter_sys_path_append]

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue, not critical and developers have just so much time. It should not be too hard to fix, IPython is open source, you are welcome ton contribute !

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just don't have this problem before and wonder if I did something wrong to make this happen.

Comment: It's https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/299. There's a PR up to fix it in https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10996.

Comment: I have this same problem. Does anyone, maybe, have a workaround for this?